# Smartphone home screen bookmark button

Tags: android, iphone, homescreen, bookmarks

I'm creating a small web site that will mostly be used with modern smart phones.

Is there a standard way to make a button that would make a bookmark on the phone home screen? Similar to iOS Safari "Add to Home Screen" -option, but with a greater support (iPhone, HTC, Blackberry etc.)

Also: Is the apple-touch-favicon also used with other smart phones or is there a standard for that too?

Thanks alot for your answers!

Comment: Nowadays I use this to generate all the needed favicons and tags: http://realfavicongenerator.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no support for web browser address to home screen in Android 2.x (maybe in 4.x). You can only add a bookmark to the home screen by adding a shorcut from the home screen menu.

Not sure about the favicon, but given the "apple-touch-" naming convention I'd take a guess and say no.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a .js script that somewhat achieves this on both platforms.

behold: [bookmark bubble](https://github.com/okamototk/jqm-mobile-bookmark-bubble)

It may be a bit finicky but fine tuned it can work as a means to "direct" the user to bookmark the page based on the platform (ios, android). As near as I can tell, this is about the closest you are going to get to a one click bookmark to home screen "button"

One other alternative for android at least, is to create an actual application. Utilizing android [intents](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) it can open up the mobile site in fullscreen (or whatever you wish really). This is a bit of a process but may be worth it depending on your situation. You can just direct users to the play store for the "mobile app" version.